# SAS new variable based on new variable's preivous value

Tags: sas

I have a time series data set of over 3,000 observations. I am trying to create a new variable that is dependent on that variable's previous value and I am having trouble getting SAS to calculate each observation in order to ensure that the previous value is calculated before it gets to the next observation.

I have set the first observation to 1. Then for the remaining observations I want SAS to calculate:

New_var = lag(new_var) * (1 + Var2)

Any ideas? I am sure it is a relatively easy answer, but I haven't been able to decipher it myself.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a retain statement instead of lag.

```
retain new_var;
new_var = new_var * (1+Var2);
```

Comment: important to note that new_var cannot exist (even if missing) on an input SET or MERGE Data Set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and reached here searching for it. I came out with the following logic and so thought of answering it here as well for future SAS enthusiasts:

1. Use (or create) an existing (or new) variable which has unique values. You may use retain statement in SAS or monotonic() function in proc sql as shown below:

   /*using proc sql*/
   proc sql;
   create table temp6 as
   select a.*, monotonic() as var3 from temp5 as a;
   quit;

   /*using data step*/
   data temp7;
   set temp5;
   retain var3;
   var3 + 1;
   run;
2. Once you have this variable, you may use the retain statement and first. flag to calculate New_Var as below. I have initialized the New_Var with 1 for the very first row. You may change the initial value accordingly.

   data temp8;
    set temp7;
    by var3;
    retain New_Var 1;
    if first.var3 then New_Var = New_Var * (1 + Var2);
    run;

Hope this helps!!